# while hosting my react app on netlify using github am getting this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify

[image]

package.json
[image]

am not able to host my web page

Comment: It suggests you can run npm install --force or npm install --legacy-peer-deps. To do this on Netlify you can use the NPM_FLAGS envi.

Also see https://answers.netlify.com/t/conflicting-peer-dependency-types-react-17-0-50/76583/2

Comment: As i know Material-UI 4.12.4 does not support react 18. did you check the version compatibility?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck